# ubuntu freeze on reboot or shutdown

Tags: suspend, freeze, reboot

This is my first question hoping to find help. The problem is that my laptop hangs and freezes.

It only happens if I restart my laptop after it was suspended // close laptop lid and open it when needed.

It happens only with Ubuntu 16.4.3 or if I run apt-get upgrade on Ubuntu 16.4.2

The problem doesn't occur on version 16.4.2 without upgrade.
info om my laptop:

- model: asus ux410uq //the same as ux310uq but with 14"
- cpu: Intel® Core™ i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz × 4
- graphic: Intel® Kabylake GT2
- graphic2: nvidia 940mx

  - using xorg xserver

**NOTE:**

- I haven't installed graphic driver as the laptop freezes if it is suspended.
- I have tried every solution out there including updating kernel and changing the grup file.

I am not a expert on Linux so if you need more information pleases write how I cat get them

This is the list of  package that will be upgraded

Any suggestion what can cause the problem.
Thank you in advance

```
################################################
    Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Calculating upgrade...
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  snap-confine
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages have been kept back:
  gnome-shell gnome-shell-common gnome-software gnome-software-common
  libegl1-mesa libgbm1 libgl1-mesa-dri libinput10 libmirclient9
  libwayland-egl1-mesa libxatracker2 linux-generic-hwe-16.04
  linux-headers-generic-hwe-16.04 linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04
  linux-signed-generic-hwe-16.04 linux-signed-image-generic-hwe-16.04
  python3-software-properties python3-update-manager
  software-properties-common software-properties-gtk ubuntu-gnome-desktop
  update-manager update-manager-core update-notifier update-notifier-common
  xserver-xorg-core-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-input-evdev-hwe-16.04
  xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-input-wacom-hwe-16.04
  xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-video-ati-hwe-16.04
  xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe-16.04
  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-video-qxl-hwe-16.04
  xserver-xorg-video-radeon-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-video-vesa-hwe-16.04
  xserver-xorg-video-vmware-hwe-16.04
The following packages will be upgraded:
  apparmor apport apport-gtk appstream apt apt-transport-https apt-utils
  base-files bash bind9-host binutils bsdutils coreutils cups cups-bsd
  cups-client cups-common cups-core-drivers cups-daemon cups-ppdc
  cups-server-common desktop-file-utils distro-info-data dnsmasq-base dnsutils
  dpkg eject evince evince-common evolution evolution-common evolution-plugins
  firefox fonts-opensymbol fwupdate fwupdate-signed gdb gdbserver gdm3
  ghostscript ghostscript-x gir1.2-evince-3.0 gir1.2-gdm-1.0
  gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0 gir1.2-gtk-3.0 gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0
  gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0 gir1.2-nmgtk-1.0 gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0
  gir1.2-soup-2.4 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 gnome-weather grub-common grub-efi-amd64
  grub-efi-amd64-bin grub-efi-amd64-signed grub2-common gstreamer1.0-alsa
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio
  gstreamer1.0-x gtk2-engines-pixbuf gvfs gvfs-backends gvfs-bin gvfs-common
  gvfs-daemons gvfs-fuse gvfs-libs iio-sensor-proxy imagemagick
  imagemagick-6.q16 imagemagick-common init init-system-helpers iproute2
  isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common kmod less libapparmor-perl libapparmor1
  libappindicator3-1 libappstream-glib8 libappstream3 libapt-inst2.0
  libapt-pkg5.0 libarchive13 libasn1-8-heimdal libbind9-140 libblkid1 libc-bin
  libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6-dbg libc6-dev libcups2 libcupscgi1 libcupsimage2
  libcupsmime1 libcupsppdc1 libdns-export162 libdns162 libdpkg-perl
  libdrm-amdgpu1 libdrm-intel1 libdrm-nouveau2 libdrm-radeon1 libdrm2
  libepoxy0 libevdocument3-4 libevent-2.0-5 libevolution libevview3-3
  libexiv2-14 libexpat1 libfdisk1 libfreetype6 libfwup0 libgail-3-0
  libgail-common libgail18 libgcrypt20 libgd3 libgdm1 libgl1-mesa-glx
  libglapi-mesa libgnutls-openssl27 libgnutls30 libgraphite2-3 libgs9
  libgs9-common libgssapi3-heimdal libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0
  libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common
  libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-bin libgtk2.0-common libhcrypto4-heimdal
  libheimbase1-heimdal libheimntlm0-heimdal libhx509-5-heimdal libicu55
  libisc-export160 libisc160 libisccc140 libisccfg140 libjasper1
  libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 libjbig2dec0 libkmod2 libkrb5-26-heimdal
  libldap-2.4-2 liblouis-data liblouis9 liblwres141 libmagickcore-6.q16-2
  libmagickcore-6.q16-2-extra libmagickwand-6.q16-2 libminiupnpc10
  libmirprotobuf3 libmount1 libmwaw-0.3-3 libnautilus-extension1a libnl-3-200
  libnl-genl-3-200 libnm-glib-vpn1 libnm-glib4 libnm-gtk-common libnm-gtk0
  libnm-util2 libnm0 libnma-common libnma0 libnspr4 libnss-myhostname libnss3
  libnss3-nssdb libpackagekit-glib2-16 libpam-systemd libpci3 libpoppler-glib8
  libpoppler58 libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulse0 libpulsedsp libpurple-bin
  libpurple0 libqt5core5a libqt5dbus5 libqt5gui5 libqt5network5 libqt5opengl5
  libqt5printsupport5 libqt5sql5 libqt5sql5-sqlite libqt5widgets5 libqt5xml5
  libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc
  libreoffice-common libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-gnome
  libreoffice-gtk libreoffice-impress libreoffice-math libreoffice-ogltrans
  libreoffice-pdfimport libreoffice-style-galaxy libreoffice-style-tango
  libreoffice-writer libroken18-heimdal librtmp1 libsane libsane-common
  libsmartcols1 libsmbclient libsndfile1 libsoup-gnome2.4-1 libsoup2.4-1
  libssl1.0.0 libsystemd0 libtasn1-6 libtiff5 libudev1
  libunity-control-center1 libuuid1 libwacom-bin libwacom-common libwacom2
  libwayland-client0 libwayland-cursor0 libwayland-server0 libwbclient0
  libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2 libwhoopsie0 libwind0-heimdal
  libxfont1 libxml2 libxml2-utils libxslt1.1 lintian linux-firmware
  linux-libc-dev locales login logrotate makedev mount multiarch-support nano
  nautilus nautilus-data network-manager network-manager-gnome openssh-client
  openssl passwd pciutils pidgin-data poppler-utils pulseaudio
  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth pulseaudio-module-x11 pulseaudio-utils
  python-libxml2 python3-apport python3-distupgrade python3-louis python3-pil
  python3-problem-report python3-uno resolvconf samba-libs sane-utils shim
  shim-signed snap-confine snapd ssh-askpass-gnome sudo systemd systemd-sysv
  tcpdump thermald ubuntu-core-launcher ubuntu-drivers-common
  ubuntu-release-upgrader-core ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk udev
  unattended-upgrades unity-control-center-faces uno-libs3 ure util-linux
  uuid-runtime vino wget whoopsie xfonts-utils xserver-common xserver-xephyr
  xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-input-all-hwe-16.04
  xserver-xorg-legacy-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-video-all-hwe-16.04 xsltproc
  xul-ext-ubufox zlib1g
316 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 38 not upgraded.
Need to get 310 MB of archives.
After this operation, 75,5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.
###################################################
```

Comment: Performing regular updates is a good thing, make it an habit. Now, *I haven't installed graphic driver* that's the problem. Open Additional drivers,l select and apply the recommended driver version. Reboot and test again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer MichaelBay. But the problem with the graphic driver is when ever it is installed laptop dosent wake after a suspend and freeze. l have tried all methods but never get it to work and survive a suspend.

Comment: And what driver version(s) have you tried and how did you install it?

Comment: almost ever version is available. the ones from nvidia website and from ppa.
NOW to avoid the problem i made apt--mark hold to
xserver-common xserver-xephyr xserver-xorg-core-hwe-16.04
  xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-input-all-hwe-16.04
  xserver-xorg-input-evdev-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hwe-16.04
  xserver-xorg-input-wacom-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-legacy-hwe-16.04
  xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-video-ati-hwe-16.04
  xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe-16.04
  xserver-xorg-video-qxl-hwe-16.4 and some other